# Permission denied when adding a range for user

Tags: docker, zsh

**I am trying to get Docker Desktop to run but it is not starting.**

I tried following this [step](https://github.com/docker/desktop-linux/issues/43#issuecomment-1178652998) and entered the following commands:

> $ echo :10000:65536 >> /etc/subuid

However, I get an error:

> zsh: permission denied: /etc/subuid

I tried running the command with sudo but I keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Redirection is done before the command is run, so sudo doesn't help. Typical workaround is to combine sudo with tee

Comment: @Shawn could you please give me an example of the command I should enter?

Comment: echo  :10000:65536  | sudo tee -a /etc/subuid